# Set delay on image and then have it removed

Tags: java, delay, game-engine

I am programming a game where as one image changes place with another and I want the second image to be removed after 200ms, something I really could use some help with.

I'm still a beginner and all help is appreciated! Answer as if you were talking to a **five year old**!

```
 public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(explode));

    image = ii.getImage();

    //this.visible = visible; 
    /*WITH THIS LINE OF CODE THE EXPLODE DOES NOT SHOW AT ALL,
    I WANT TO MAKE SURE IT SHOWS BUT ONLY FOR 200MS*/
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a single shot Swing `Timer`..  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scheduled thread for it. You can use the [ScheduledExcecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) for it

```
private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();


public void displayImageFor200Ms(){
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(explode));
    image = ii.getImage();

    scheduler.schedule(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {  
            // remove image now!
        }
    }, 200 , TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

don't forget to shut down the scheduler when you don't need it anymore (you could use a global, pooled Scheduler for all your delayed actions and shut it down when your game is over)

Answer (score 0):

Since you shouldn't do these time blocking methods like `Thread.sleep(200)` in the EDT, here is another solution with the `Timer` and `TimerTask` classes:

```
public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
    ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(explode));

    // show / hide image
    ii.setVisible(visible);

    if (visible) { // only hide image, if it's previously set to visible
        new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                ii.setVisible(false);
            }
        }, 200); // hide it after 200 ms
    }
}
```

Thanks @AndrewThompson for the advice!

Comment: Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread) - the GUI will 'freeze' when that happens. Instead of calling `Thread.sleep(n)` implement a Swing `Timer` for repeating tasks or a `SwingWorker` for long running tasks.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for this advice! I was sure, there is a better way to do this ;)

Comment: If you edit the answer to advise a `Timer` (feel free to adapt my comment), I can delete some noise and up-vote.

Comment: Umm.. I did state a  *"**Swing** [`Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)"* ;)  It is handy for this task, for two reasons. 1) It has a [`setRepeats(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setRepeats%28boolean%29) method (satisfying one of the requirements in a single code line) 2) It ensures the updates to the GUI are performed on the EDT - which is important for robust GUI updates.  For the moment I'll remove the down vote, but leave the comment.

Comment: I'm sorry, that I'd misunderstood your advice! :)  Anyway, this is at least a better solution than my first one ;)

Comment: *"Anyway, this is at least a better solution than my first one"*  True, and I'm feeling it is already a better answer than the question deserves, given the OP seems to have ignored my advice to post an MCVE..